# First Integral of Pendulum with Friction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-theory

How can we prove that an ODE does not have a first integral (i.e., a constant of motion that is conserved along the trajectories)? For example, is it true that the pendulum system of ODEs $$\dot x_1 = x_2$$ $$\dot x_2 =  -a\:\sin(x_1) - b\:x_2$$ does not have a first integral?

My intuition says that for ODE systems which represent a physical system with loss, the first integral (equivalently, the energy function) does not exist.

Comment: What do you mean by the energy function does not exist? For example, the trivial solution will have $0$ energy.

Comment: The conserved "energy" (first integral) is $H(t,x_1,x_2)=\frac{x_2^2}{2}+b\int_0^t{x_2^2(s)ds}-a\cos(x_1)$.

Comment: @Botond: I mean a first integral of motion in the sense of a conserved quantity which remains constant on trajectories.

Comment: @RTJ: But this is explicitly time-dependent. Since we finally want to use constants of motion to obtain the properties of the motion without solving the ODE, I think this time-dependent first integral is not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a first integral representing some form of energy does exist; however, it might not be constant on trajectories. That's the case for your system, it's dissipative so you don't have a first integral of motion, in the sense of a conserved quantity.

For systems of the form 
$$\dot{x}_1=x_2$$
$$\dot{x}_2=F(x_1)$$
you can in general find a first integral of motion that represents some form of energy being conserved on the system's trajectories. However, when 
$$\dot{x}_2=F(x_1,x_2)\,,$$
as in your case, then the system is dissipative and there is no first integral of motion; you can try to integrate the equation, but the resulting quantity will not be maintained constant on trajectories. Hope this helps you in your question!

Comment: Thanks @Anon. It seems it should be challenging to prove that a system does NOT have any first integral of motion (in the sense of a conserved quantity). Am I right? Is there any rigorous way to prove it?

Comment: In physical systems, there are ways to prove that they are dissipative. For instance in the pendulum equations (or the general harmonic oscillator), you can take the conservative system and show that the energy is conserved. Then if you take the same energy and calculate its time-derivative along trajectories of the dissipative system, you will find that the energy is strictly decreasing; it is now a Lyapunov function for your system. It can be used e.g. to prove that the origin is a globally stable fixed point for the dissipative system; so you prove that energy is always decreasing.

Comment: But of course in these cases we use our physical understanding of the system to show that the "energy" cannot be constant along trajectories, since we transfer this quantity from the conservative system. So I'm not sure on what degree does that actually qualify as a _rigorous_ way.

Comment: Thanks @Anon. That makes sense.

Comment: There is a simple rigorous way to prove that such system can't have an autonomous locally non-constant first integral. The reason for this is that your system has asymptotically stable equilibrium. Since a first integral is at least continuous and all trajectories in the equilibrium's basin of attraction converge to it, the first integral must be constant on the whole basin of attraction. But this is an open set and being constant on open set contradicts with reasonable assumption that the first integral must be locally non-constant. ...

Comment: ... Because of that conservative systems (i.e., systems with the first integral) can never have asymptotically stable (or completely unstable) equilibria.